# Why are Idealists not entitled to believe in laws of nature?

Tags: idealism

<sub>Source: p 120, *Philosophy: A Complete Introduction* (2012) by [Prof Sharon Kaye (MA PhD (Philosophy), U. Toronto)](http://sites.jcu.edu/philosophy/professor/sharon-kaye/). The following question appears in Chapter 8 entitled *Hume and causality*.</sub>

> 4. Which of the following is entitled to believe in laws of nature?
>
> a) Empiricists    b) Rationalists    c) Materialists    d) Idealists
>
> [p 7, see also p 12 :] The view that the material world around us is not real is called **idealism**.
>
> [p 64, cp. p 73:] The fundamental theme in Descartes's philosophy is reason: we discover innate truths through the power of clear thinking. In his hands, the inward-looking approach we have seen running through Plato and Anselm becomes the epistemology known as **rationalism**.

p 219 states (b) as the only answer with no explanation. I understand why (b) is an answer (as Laws of Nature supply reasons for truths), but why is (d) incorrect? I can imagine an Idealist who tries to understand the world by relying on Laws of Nature using maths and physics, because she has already adjudged the material world  unreal and unreliable.

[This website](https://www.eskimo.com/%7Emsharlow/idealism.htm) asserts the following which would vindicate (d):

> Actually, the idealistic concept of the material world is logically compatible with the scientific view of matter. Idealism does not say that the natural world is unreal; it does not say that the laws of nature are mere inventions of the human mind; it does not say we can change the world magically by thinking differently.

Comment: "The view that the material world around us is not real is called idealism" is charming in its plain question begging since idealists reject that the world around us is material (most also accept that it is real). The author's apparent belief that philosophical questions can be supplied with multiple choice answer keys makes me doubt even more that this is an adequate book for studying philosophy. And contra the book, the correct answer is any of the above.

Comment: I think Kaye must just mean that the debate between (c) and (d) is completely orthogonal to the debate about the status of laws of nature. I can't see any reason to think idealists couldn't believe in laws of nature.

Comment: ... unless maybe she thinks that idealists all have to be empiricists and empiricists all have to reject laws of nature. but at any rate, it's clear that there are empiricists who believe in laws of nature (Hume isn't one, but David Lewis is.) And there are materialists who believe in laws of nature (david armstrong is one).

Comment: Idealists certainly believe in the laws of nature. Berkeley said that there's no reality "out there," but that the apparent continuity of reality is ensured by God. He was a Catholic bishop so we can put his belief into context. The contemporary simulation theorists say there's no reality out there but that the apparent continuity of nature is provided for by the great computer in the sky. We no longer take Berkeley seriously but the TED talkers can't stop telling us about simulation theory. Go figure. In either case, there are definite laws of nature as implemented by God or computer.

Comment: I feel Conifold is right to question the adequacy of the book. It appears to be daft.

Answer (score 1):

If idealists believe that nothing exists but non-physical minds and states or activities of mind, then they cannot believe in laws of physical nature since there is *ex hypothesi* no physical nature and hence can be no law-governed laws of nature.

There is no reason, though, why if idealists believe the world is a mental construction, and non-physical, that  construction cannot to exhibit lawlike regularities - which here just means 'laws of nature' (non-physical nature).

Comment: If idealism is true then the laws of Nature are a product of Mind or, if you like, they simply are the laws of Mind. No problem. Of course, 'Mind' here would not mean human mind. .